# Handlebars.js - how to trim any unwanted characters like spaces or symbols on a username placeholder within <p> tag in handlebars template given below

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, email-templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<script src="handlebars-v4.7.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="welcome"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myInfo = "<p>This is a notification that a new user has just registered: First name: {{firstname}}, Last name: {{lastname}}, E-mail: {{email}}, User name: {{username}}</p>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(myInfo);
var data = template({firstname: "jenny", lastname: "caroz", email: "jenny.caroz@example.com", username: "Ms.+-@!jenny.caroz+-!#"});
document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML +=data;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried Handlebars helpers string functions like trim or chop but logic failed, I was not sure how to apply them on just username within 'p' tag as shown in above template. I want result of my username to be jenny.caroz as opposed to what's being passed in data above as Ms.+-@!jenny.caroz+-!#. The pattern of usrname should be whatever present in first name and lastname, in this case - jennycaroz. Any characters other than "jennycaroz" should be treated as unwanted characters within username.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the characters you wish to remove from the `username`? In other words, how do you determine which characters are "unwanted"?

Comment: The pattern of username should be whatever present in first name and lastname, in this case - firstname: "jenny", lastname: "caroz", so username should be jennycaroz. Any characters other than "jennycaroz" should be treated as unwanted characters in the username

Comment: Then why not just use the `firstname` and `lastname`? `{{firstname}}{{lastname}}`

Comment: sometimes when user is registered website settings is appending Ms./Mr./Mrs. and sometimes unwanted symbols. so we are looking a way to trim them off

Comment: If it isn't a specific pattern of characters that you are removing from each `username`, then I think you would need to create a helper using a regular expression and I think it would end up being fragile and breaking in some situations. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/tqgajf04/